# Cakephp 2.x Mail connection with Office365

Tags: email, cakephp, outlook, smtp, office365

I am developing an application where my client is using Office 365 for his emails , etc... I am trying to connect Cakephp mail with office 365 SMTP but without any success.
Here is my code:

```
public $default = array(
    'from' => array('info@*****.com' => 'Company Name'),
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'host' => 'tls://smtp.office365.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'username' => 'info@*****.com',
    'password' => '*******',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => true,
    'tls' => true
);
```

The error iam getting is Unable to connect to SMTP server. Also I tried the following hosts with and without tls:

1. ssl://smtp-mail.outlook.com
2. Smtp.mail.apac.microsoftonline.com (on this i was getting timeout error)
3. pod51022.outlook.com

Thanks.

Comment: OK The issue solved,
the problem was in cakephp version, i was using 2.2.9 i update the version and problem solved.

As of 2.3.0 you can also enable TLS SMTP using the tls option.

Comment: did you use the host smtp.office365.com? if so, with or without the tls://  prefix?

Answer (score 4):

try following :

```
    'public $default = array(
'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
'port' =>25,
'from' => array('info@*****.com' => 'Company Name'),
'transport' => 'Smtp',
'username' => 'info@*****.com',
'password' => '*******',
'tls'=>true );'
```

in case it don't work,
try after removing password,

make sure that
email id is authenticated to send anonymous mail on office365.